# Joomla 3: Move folder content to another folder via PHP

Tags: php, joomla

I have a custom file in Joomla 3.2 where, when accessed, it's running a script with various tasks. One of which is to copy the CONTENTS of a folder into an existing different folder. I've trying with this code:

```
$src = JPATH_SITE . "/folder";
$dest = JPATH_SITE . "/newfolder";

JFolder::copy($src, $dest, $force=true);
```

I've tried just about every possible way to designate the $src, but no matter what I try I get:

```
Error: -1 Source folder not found
```

I have tried with "folder" and "newfolder" permissions set at both 755 and 777. My site path structure is mysite.com/folder and mysite.com/newfolder, so both src and dest are on the main level of directories for this site. I'm not sure if JFolder::copy is actually what I need here or not, but it's what I've found thus far that can potentially accomplish what I need... moving of the folder CONTENTS.

Also, when I echo src, dest and getcwd, I get:

```
getcwd = /var/www/vhosts/mysite/administrator
$src = /var/www/vhosts/mysite/folder
$dest = /var/www/vhosts/mysite/newfolder
```

I imagine it's a small detail that I'm not experienced enough to know or see.

I can do this with SSH, but I'm trying to accomplish it within this Joomla file to remove the manual process in SSH.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to copy the folder or the files in the folder? JFolder::copy I think is going to copy the folder itself not the contents.  I would think you want JFolder:files and then to use JFile:copy.

Answer (score 0):

`JPATH_SITE` does not contain a trailing slash.

You need to do:

```
$src = JPATH_SITE . "/folder";
$dest = JPATH_SITE . "/newfolder";
```

Comment: Thanks but I actually already had it this way. I just left out the slashes when I posted the question. So this isn't the issue. Thanks very much for pointing that out though! I did update my post. Any other ideas?

Comment: Well the error is quite clear, the source folder does not exist.

Comment: Yet they DO. :) Those two folders are 100% most definitely there... and in the exact location as seen in the echo.